# Is the arc length parameter equal to the arc length function?

Tags: differential-geometry

In my Differential Geometry notes, we can define for each path $\beta : J \to \mathbb{R}^n $ an arc length function $S:J \to \mathbb{R} $ defined as the oriented length w.r.t. a point $a \in J$. Then $\alpha = \beta\circ S^{-1}(x)$ is an arc length path, where $S^{-1}(x)$ is defined on the $Im(S)$.

Now we want to calculate the arc length parameter. My tutor says that from the above it follows that $s$, the parameter of $\alpha$, equals $S(t)$ with $t$ the parameter of $\beta$.

I don't understand this. Maybe I'm missing something very stupid.